# WebDriver.quit() : does it couse chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener() to trigger as it closes browser windows

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

When I execute selenium test for my chrome extension, on `WebDriver.quit()` it is now causing that event `chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener()` from that background script of my chrome extensions:

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: I want that listener to be executed, as now it is getting ignored on webdriver.quit()

Comment: Try this: add "background" to the "permissions" list of your extension's manifest.json, then close the windows one by one explicitly using webdriver or selenium commands, not by using quit(). Then make a pause like 100ms for your extension to process the event and call quit().